# Connecting to Jenkins with ssh key

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I want to use the Jenkins CLI, and for that I think that I need to generate an SSH key pair on my machine and put the public key of that pair in the Jenkins server configuration.

I generated an SSH key on my machine with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my_email@example.com"` and I'm trying to give the public key to the Jenkins server.

However, if I go to **Jenkins -> Credentials -> System -> Global Credentials**, the only SSH-related option is `SSH Username with private key`.

Shouldn't it ask for an SSH public key instead of a private key?

Am I making any mistakes in my assumptions?

Comment: The `SSH Username with private key` in Global Credentials is used to ssh to a machine or do something through ssh during running a test job on Jenkins. For your use case, I feel you should put the public key onto the server where you run your Jenkins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the public key to your user account in Jenkins.

Click your username in the top-right of any page in Jenkins, click Configure in the sidebar, and there you'll find a SSH Public Key textfield to paste into.